# Is there a way to preserve Google Docs added tabs in TipTap (or similar WYSIWYG Editor)?

Tags: html, vue.js, google-docs, text-editor, tiptap

I'm writing a web app that uses TipTap as its rich text Editor, and I'm realizing that there's an issue when pasting certain content from Google Docs into the editor. Google Docs picks up on when your paragraphs are beginning with indents, so it starts adding them for you whenever you hit Enter/Return. However, these Google-added tabs don't actually exist in the text, so when you copy into another text editor, or even export to plain text right from Google Docs, you lose the indents. This is what I mean:

Google Docs Source:
[image: Google Docs Source]

When Pasted into TipTap Editor:
[image: TipTap Paste Result]

Am I just out of luck with this kind of thing, or is there a workaround that I'm missing? Any input is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `CTRL+SHIFT+V (Cmd+Shift+V on Mac)` to paste the information instead of `CTRL+V` to paste the text? Since `CTRL+V` keeps the styling from a rich format document like Google Docs.

While Adding the `Shift` key into your paste shortcut strips all formatting from the original copied text.

Comment: Yeah I thought the same, but no luck. Google isn't actually adding any formatting by the looks, they're just rendering the text with automatic indents that don't appear in the raw text itself.

Comment: I think it is working odd for me, I tried to make a test, and it was not even adding the indentations of the ones that I added manually either.